# disabled exceptions and noexcept()

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, noexcept

`std::swap` is declared this way:

```
template <class T> void swap (T& a, T& b)
    noexcept (is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value && 
              is_nothrow_move_assignable<T>::value);
```

If I disable exceptions in my program (like with `-fno-exceptions` for **g++**) will `std::swap` use move operations for my custom types if they are move-enabled no matter if they are noexcept or not?

**EDIT: follow-up question:**

After realizing that std::swap will always use moves if my type has them, my real question is what happens to traits like `is_nothrow_move_assignable<>`?

Will `std::vector` always use moves when reallocating if my types have `noexcept(true)` move operations?

Comment: The compiler's ``move`` rules are orthogonal to exceptions.

Comment: @AmiTavory the move rules yes, but what about the traits like ```is_nothrow_move_constructible```?

Comment: Write a short (3 line) test program that prints out the result of `is_nothrow_move_constructible` compile it with and without -fno-exceptions

Comment: @RichardCritten I just tried it - using ```-fno-exceptions``` does not make everything ```noexcept(true)```...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The noexcept-specification on `swap` solely tells the **user** where she can use `swap` without encountering an exception. The **implementation** is practically always equivalent to

```
auto tmp = std::move(a);
a = std::move(b);
b = std::move(tmp);
```

Which moves the objects around if, and only if, overload resolution selects a move assignment operator and/or constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. `noexcept` simply specifies that `std::swap` will not throw if `T`'s move constructor and move assignment will not throw. It does not affect the behavior of the body of `swap` whatsoever - which will use `T`'s move constructor and move assignment regardless of whether or not they throw and regardless of whether or not you compile with exceptions enabled.